# Testing Artifactory Credentials

Tags: security, gradle, artifactory

Is there a way to test artifactory credentials and if I can successfully access a repository? running from the command line I cannot see if the credentials are used and from a browser with the `?trace` appended to the url denies the anonymous user access.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you need to perform this check as part of automation/scripting? what do you mean by running from the comman line - the JFrog CLI?

Comment: I'm trying to resolve the SNAPSHOT dependency. I am able to resolve the RELEASE artifact fine and my set up for both the repo and build.gradle both look correct.

Comment: please provide more details: what are you trying to resolve and how, what is the error you are getting, any relevant Artifactory log entries you can provide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make use of the [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Example-DeployinganArtifact) to test your credentials. Access it from the command line via the `curl` command:

```
curl -u myUser:myP455w0rd! -X GET "http://<artifactory-url>:8080/artifactory/api/build"
```

If your credentials are correct, this should show you all builds in Artifactory.

Comment: If your artifactory has many builds in, this response can take a long time.  It is much faster if you use HEAD instead of GET

Comment: I got the error: "curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy:" and realised -x should be -X.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ! curl --fail-with-body --noproxy '*' --netrc --head 'https://<artifactory-url>:8080/artifactory/api/npm/auth' ; then
    # handle error here
fi
```

In my case:

- using .netrc to keep information about credentials;
- artifactory is behind nginx proxy;
- accepted answer does not work, as it returns HTTP 404 when there are no builds[1].

Above curl command works like this:

- For wrong credentials, HTTP 401 is returned.
- For anonymous call, HTTP 400 is returned.
- For correct credentials, HTTP 200 is returned.

[1]

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "No builds were found"
  } ]
}
```